# How to modify a cell outside cellForRowAt Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uidatepicker

Currently my code is something like this, where I am setting a datePicker in the cell

**Code A works**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("DailyTimesTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! DailyTimesTableViewCell
    cell.endTimeTapped = { (button) -> DailyTimesTableViewCell in
        cell.datePicker.date = self.convertToDateObject(timeString: endTime as! String)
    } 
    return cell
}
```

I would like to modify the datePicker in the cell based on some logic, so when I try the below Code B, to modify the datePicker in the cell using a callback `setTimeInDatePicker` it doesn't seem to work.

Please advice where I could be going wrong.

**Code B: Doesn't work**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("DailyTimesTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! DailyTimesTableViewCell
    cell.endTimeTapped = { (button) -> DailyTimesTableViewCell in
    self.setTimeInDatePicker(time: endTime!, cell: cell){ modifiedCell in
                    return modifiedCell
                }
    } 
    return cell
}


func setTimeInDatePicker(time: String, cell: DailyTimesTableViewCell, completionHandler: @escaping(DailyTimesTableViewCell) -> DailyTimesTableViewCell) {

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    let row     = cell.tag
    let rows    = self.timesArray.count

    if self.startTimeHighlighted{
        // Setting minimum startTime for datePicker
        if row == 0{ // For first row
            let minStartTimeString      =   "0:05 am"
            cell.datePicker.minimumDate = self.convertToDateObject(timeString: minStartTimeString)
        }
        else if row > 0 {   // For remaining rows
            let endTimeStringOfPreviousCell = self.timesArray[row - 1]["endTime"]!
            let endTimeObjectOfPreviousCell = self.convertToDateObject(timeString: endTimeStringOfPreviousCell)
            cell.datePicker.minimumDate     = endTimeObjectOfPreviousCell
        }

        // Setting maximum startTime for datepicker
        let endTimeString           =   self.timesArray[row]["endTime"]!
        let endTimeObject           =   self.convertToDateObject(timeString: endTimeString)
        let maxStartTimeObject      =   endTimeObject.addingTimeInterval(-5 * 60.0)            // removing 5mins
        cell.datePicker.maximumDate =   maxStartTimeObject

        // Setting selected date in as startTime title
        let dateString = self.convertDateToString(cell.datePicker.date)
        cell.startTime.setTitle(dateString, for: .normal)

        // Saving updated date to the timesArray
        self.timesArray[row]["startTime"] = dateString
        //print("endTime in DatePickerChanged: \(self.timesArray[row]["endTime"])")
        print("timesArray when startTimeHighlighted: \(self.timesArray)")
        completionHandler(cell)

    }
    else if self.endTimeHighlighted{
        print("datePicker changed 3")
        // Setting minimum endTime for datePicker

        let startTimeString = self.timesArray[row]["startTime"]
        let startTimeObject       =   self.convertToDateObject(timeString: startTimeString!)
        let minEndTimeObject    =   startTimeObject.addingTimeInterval(5 * 60.0)            // adding 5mins
        cell.datePicker.minimumDate = minEndTimeObject

        // Setting maximum endTime for datePicker
        if rows == 1 || row + 1 == self.timesArray.count{ // For first and last row
            let maxEndTimeString = "11:55 pm"
            cell.datePicker.maximumDate = self.convertToDateObject(timeString: maxEndTimeString)
        }
        else{ // If more than one row
            let nextCellStartTime           =   self.timesArray[row + 1]["startTime"]!
            let nextCellStartTimeObject     =   self.convertToDateObject(timeString: nextCellStartTime)
            cell.datePicker.maximumDate     =   nextCellStartTimeObject
        }

        // Setting selected date in as endTime title
        let dateString = self.convertDateToString(cell.datePicker.date)
        cell.endTime.setTitle(dateString, for: .normal)

        // Saving updated date to the timesArray
        self.timesArray[row]["endTime"] = dateString
        print("timesArray when endTimeHighlighted: \(self.timesArray)")

        completionHandler(cell)

    }

    tableView.endUpdates()

}
```

Comment: It seems you don't understand how callback closures work. Usually they don't return anything.

Comment: Are you sure the method gets called at all?

Comment: You also have another option that is to update your tableView's datasource and then use `didSet` on it and call `tableView.reloadData()`. That way your data would also be made aware of the update.

Comment: @vadian, I agree that callback closures are not right for this job. When I try to modify the cell by passing it to this function `setTimeInDatePicker(time: String, cell: DailyTimesTableViewCell)` the cell is returned even before this function has finished executing (for e.g when I try @thomas answer, it doesn't work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are confusing completionHandlers with something else.

Usually one uses completionHandlers when a task is asynchronous. So in short you start a task (typically network) and when it's completed (which could take very very long) you have a handler you can call to let the application know it has finished.

As the application didn't wait for this very long async task to finish it continued running and isn't at the same state it was when the task was first started. In short, whatever you are returning in your completion handler will/should not be used.

Based on that, and the fact that everything seems to be synchronous you could refactor your function like so:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("DailyTimesTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! DailyTimesTableViewCell
    cell.endTimeTapped = { [unowned self](_) in
        // Use unowned to make sure you don't create a retain-cycle
        self.setTimeInDatePicker(time: endTime!, cell: cell)
    } 
    return cell
}


func setTimeInDatePicker(time: String, cell: DailyTimesTableViewCell) {

    let row     = cell.tag
    let rows    = self.timesArray.count

    if self.startTimeHighlighted{
        // Setting minimum startTime for datePicker
        if row == 0{ // For first row
            let minStartTimeString      =   "0:05 am"
            cell.datePicker.minimumDate = self.convertToDateObject(timeString: minStartTimeString)
        }
        else if row > 0 {   // For remaining rows
            let endTimeStringOfPreviousCell = self.timesArray[row - 1]["endTime"]!
            let endTimeObjectOfPreviousCell = self.convertToDateObject(timeString: endTimeStringOfPreviousCell)
            cell.datePicker.minimumDate     = endTimeObjectOfPreviousCell
        }

        // Setting maximum startTime for datepicker
        let endTimeString           =   self.timesArray[row]["endTime"]!
        let endTimeObject           =   self.convertToDateObject(timeString: endTimeString)
        let maxStartTimeObject      =   endTimeObject.addingTimeInterval(-5 * 60.0)            // removing 5mins
        cell.datePicker.maximumDate =   maxStartTimeObject

        // Setting selected date in as startTime title
        let dateString = self.convertDateToString(cell.datePicker.date)
        cell.startTime.setTitle(dateString, for: .normal)

        // Saving updated date to the timesArray
        self.timesArray[row]["startTime"] = dateString
        //print("endTime in DatePickerChanged: \(self.timesArray[row]["endTime"])")
        print("timesArray when startTimeHighlighted: \(self.timesArray)")

    }
    else if self.endTimeHighlighted{
        print("datePicker changed 3")
        // Setting minimum endTime for datePicker

        let startTimeString = self.timesArray[row]["startTime"]
        let startTimeObject       =   self.convertToDateObject(timeString: startTimeString!)
        let minEndTimeObject    =   startTimeObject.addingTimeInterval(5 * 60.0)            // adding 5mins
        cell.datePicker.minimumDate = minEndTimeObject

        // Setting maximum endTime for datePicker
        if rows == 1 || row + 1 == self.timesArray.count{ // For first and last row
            let maxEndTimeString = "11:55 pm"
            cell.datePicker.maximumDate = self.convertToDateObject(timeString: maxEndTimeString)
        }
        else{ // If more than one row
            let nextCellStartTime           =   self.timesArray[row + 1]["startTime"]!
            let nextCellStartTimeObject     =   self.convertToDateObject(timeString: nextCellStartTime)
            cell.datePicker.maximumDate     =   nextCellStartTimeObject
        }

        // Setting selected date in as endTime title
        let dateString = self.convertDateToString(cell.datePicker.date)
        cell.endTime.setTitle(dateString, for: .normal)

        // Saving updated date to the timesArray
        self.timesArray[row]["endTime"] = dateString
        print("timesArray when endTimeHighlighted: \(self.timesArray)")

    }

}
```

Note how the endTimeTapped closure makes user of `[unowned self]` to protect against retain-cycles.

You can also notice that the beginUpdate/endUpdate has been removed. The reason is that you are not doing anything that impacts the height of the cell in question, you are simply changing the date, so you don't need to trigger a refresh of the tableView as the change will be applied automatically.

Check if that did something for you?!

N.B. The cell being a class, what you send as parameter to `setTimeInDatePicker` is a reference to it so you really don't need to return anything so you already have it.

Comment: thanks for the clarification on completion handlers. When I tried your suggestion unfortunately the cell is being returned before the function `setTimeInDatePicker ` has finished executing.

Comment: I think that I am missing something, could you also add the code for. your cell in your question?

Comment: I was actually setting some flags incorrectly, which is why your suggestion was not working, however with that set, its working. This also seems to work `cell.endTimeTapped = { (button) -> DailyTimesTableViewCell in`, Many Thanks for clear explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you just want to be able to mess with a cell after some callback or within some other function. You can use `tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath)` to accomplish this goal whenever you need to. Note that this function returns a `UITableViewCell` instead of whatever custom cell type you have, so you'll have to cast it as `(cell as? YourCustomCellClass)?.whateverFunctionOrPropertyHere`. Think about how you want your information to be passed around - setting a completion block on the cell isn't a bad idea, but there are also other ways to do it.